# Error trying to install opencv-python on windows10

Tags: pip

When I entered:

`D:\QMDownload\SoftMgr\pycharm\Anaconda\Scripts>pip install opencv-python http://pypi.douban.com/simple/ --trusted-host  pypi.douban.com`

It comes out

> ERROR: Cannot unpack file
> C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-unpack-g0qoh45r\simple.html
> (downloaded from
> C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-iqogfuxk, content-type:
> text/html); cannot detect archive format ERROR: Cannot determine
> archive format of

Comment: It seems like you had a download error or the package is broken. You might want to retry it or use a different version. Also, do you really need to use that server? If it's the same package as available on pypi.org and you have access to that server, you could just run `pip install opencv-python`. That worked for me.

Comment: Thank you ，I have resolved the problem by installing opencv-python.exe because my mirrors is not good